# OpenSSL/OCSP Stapling; How to access SSLContext in callback passed to SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_status_cb(...)?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

In order to generate a response to a OCSP Request, a callback needs to be specified with the function `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_status_cb()`:

```
long SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_status_cb(SSL_CTX *ctx, int (*callback)(SSL *, void *));
```

Inside the function `int callback(SSL, void*)` it needs to be checked wither the signed-time-stamped OCSP response of the CA is present in the current SSL context, or not.

- How can this be achieved?
- How do I get access to the SSL Context from inside the callback?
- What is actually passed as second argument when the callback is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is actually passed as second argument when the callback is called?

From [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_status_cb.html): *"The callback will be passed as an argument the value previously set via a call to SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_status_arg()"*.

> How do I get access to the SSL Context from inside the callback?

By using [SSL_get_SSL_CTX](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get_SSL_CTX.html).

> How can this be achieved?

It is far from trivial to check an OCSP response. You might want to check the [implementation of SSL_OCSP_response_verify](https://metacpan.org/source/CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88/SSLeay.xs#L7167) in the Net::SSLeay Perl module.